# Puppeteer testing dialog/modal input feilds

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog, puppeteer

I'm new to Puppeteer and have been using it to do end-to-end for a webpage with a modal to input payment details. My goal is to test all input fields and submit the inputted data.

**Expected result -**
Click on modal button > open modal > input data in text field > submit data

**Actual result -**
Click on the modal button > Nothing appears to happen from here onwards and neither is any amount actually sent to the API but the test passes

```
// Require puppeteer
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

let browser;
let page;
const appUrlBase = 'http://localhost:8080';

// Create an instance of the chrome browser
beforeAll(async () => {
    browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        devtools: true
    });

    page = await browser.newPage();
});

describe('Payment test', () => {
    jest.setTimeout(600000);
    test('payment dialog box', async () => {
        await page.waitForSelector('[data-testid="payBtn"]')
        await page.click('[data-testid="payBtn"]') // Modal button
        await page.on('dialog', async dialog => {
            await page.waitForSelector('[data-testid="paymentContainer"]')
            await page.click('[data-testid="payAmount"]') // input field for payment amount
            await page.type(300)
            await page.click('[data-testid="paymentPayBtn"]')
            await dialog.dismiss()
        })
        await browser.close()
    });
});
```

Is there somewhere I'm going wrong?